# In C++, how to choose to run a specific member function without using if-statements?

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, constructor, member

I would like to understand if there is an 'elegant' way in which one can choose to run a particular (c++) class member function, based on user input.

For example let us say we have a class such that:

```
class myClass
{
    int foo;
    myClass(int input) { foo = input;}
    void runMyFunction() 
    { 
        if ( foo == 1) 
        {
            function1();
        }
        else if (foo == 2)
        {
            function2();
        } 
    }


    void function1();
    void function2();
};
```

What I would like to do, is that if a user specifies `input=1` in the constructor, then `function1()` is called when the `runMyFunction()` member is called, but if the user had specified `input=2` in the constructor, then `function2()` should be called instead.

My question is, is there a more elegant way to go this without an `if` statement? The impetus is that I would rather not have the code go through this check over and over again, since I will be using this call in a loop. Is there a more elegant way to 'set' which function is going to be called without `if` statements in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Are you comfortable with function pointers?

Comment: You can use a `std:map`, where the key is the possible user input, and the value is the function you want to execute.

Comment: @Beta I have never used them, but if that is a good way, I would be willing to learn them now.

Comment: @Learnaholic Is your condition evaluated at compile time, or at runtime actually?

Comment: [Good reading] (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Comment: Look up the `Command Pattern`

Comment: First thing: in my opinion you should avoid function pointers in `C++`. They are `C` language standard and don't comply very much with the `Object Oriented` paradigm. Second thing: your solution seems to be the most reliable (when compared to function pointers). Why don't you use a `switch case` (for 3 or more options) or a `ternary operator` (in case of only 2 options)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, at runtime, the constructor will be called once, but after that, the runMyFunction() is going to be called many many times within a loop.

Comment: These days with modern compilers, I recommend reading about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) rather than function pointer, and member functions pointers are even worse.

Comment: Besides, you could use an `enumerator` to make your code more 'elegant' as you said.

Comment: And also, one solution might be e.g. [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with an `int` key and a `std::function` as data, to map some integer to some function to be called.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino I am trying to not use if-statements or switch-statements because it seems wasteful to call this and 'recheck' every single time runMyFunction() is called. Isn't there a way to 'set' which function should run once, and then never check again? That is what I am trying to figure out. Thanks

Comment: In that case, I believe that @Loki Astari solution will fit you well.

Comment: I would personally just use a pointer to member function. Declare it as `void (myClass::*funcPtr)();`. Initialize in constructor as `funcPtr = &myClass::function1/2;` And call it as `(this->*funcPtr)();` This is too trivial of a use case to introduce the overhead of `std::function` or `(unordered_)map`\

Comment: @Praetorian Thank you, would you mind putting your first suggestion as an answer? Cheers.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino How would you use an enumerator in a case like this? Thanks.

Comment: That would make your code more elegant, but wouldn't solve your request (only setting the path for the function once during class creation).

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can use the command pattern.
You just need to set up a array of function method pointers.

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>>  actionCommand = 
      {[](){}, // Zero based index.
       [this](){this->function1();},
       [this](){this->function2();}
      };

void runMyFunction() 
    { 
        actionCommand[foo]();

        // or 

        actionCommand.at(foo)(); // throws exception if foo is not in
                                 // correct range.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, however how would say, actionCommand[1] VS actionCommand[2] be defined in the class? I am unclear as to how to use it in this particularity, what with the class members involved.

Comment: A little yes, it is new to me so I need to learn this. What I am trying to figure out is where the actionCommand function you have here, sits within my class structure? Thanks.

Comment: @Learnaholic: `actionCommand` is a normal member of your object. Just place it above your declaration to `foo`

Comment: Why do we need the overhead of a vector? I thought OP wanted to set which function was called once in the constructor.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: In this case you don't. But reading some of the comments I thought that explaining the command pattern may have been useful to the OP.

Comment: @Learnaholic: Since you set `foo` in the constructor. You can just use a single variable to represent the function that you initialize in the constructor. So rather than a runtime `switch` in `runMyFunction()` you have a `switch` in the constructor that initializes this variable. Since you now have the function in a variable you can  just call it.

Answer (score 4):

As Praetorian mentioned in comments you can initialize a member function pointer in the constructor:

```
class MyClass {
    using FuncPtrType = void (MyClass::*)();
    FuncPtrType myFunction;
  public:
    MyClass(int input) {
        if (input == 1)
          myFunction = &MyClass::function1;
        else 
          myFunction = &MyClass::function2;    
    }

    void runMyFunction() { 
      (this->*myFunction)();
    }
    void function1();
    void function2();
};
```

If you find the syntax for member function pointers offensive you could use `std::function`:

```
class MyClass {
    std::function<void(MyClass*)> myFunction;
  public:
    MyClass(int input) {
        if (input == 1)
          myFunction = &MyClass::function1;
        else 
          myFunction = &MyClass::function2;    
    }

    void runMyFunction() { 
      myFunction(this);
    }
    void function1();
    void function2();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is elegant or not, but maybe you could have function1 and function2 accept the input, and then the if statements could be placed in function1 and function2, and then execute or just return.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a switch statement. There is a simple tutorial to follow here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm

Put simply, I would do something like this

```
//while user input not equal to x
  // switch (input)
    // case A:
       function 1();
       break;
    // case B:
      .....
    //default:
       //this is the case to use if the input doesn't match any of your predefined cases. You might print a warning here, and reprint your answers.
```

Good luck

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't a switch statement be evaluated every single time in a loop? I do not want this to happen.

Comment: Yes it would be, I missed that part of your question. You'll need to refer to one of the answers in that case. Perhaps investigate the command pattern, although it is a touch more complicated.